# (Yet) Another attempt at embedding free group on three letters inside a free group on two letters

Tags: group-theory, free-groups, universal-property, combinatorial-group-theory

This question could have been asked by several users. Here is my attempt. This could possibly be completely in the wrong direction. So I attempt to show $F(\{x,y,z\}) $ is a subgroup of $F(\{a,b\})$. My intention is to exploit the universal mapping property (UMP) (and it could be in the wrong direction but anyway I'll give it a try for reasons stated below). To begin with, we have the natural injection $i:\{x,y,z\}\to F(\{x,y,z\})$ s.t $i(x)=x,i(y)=y,i(z)=z$ and the map $f:\{x,y,z\}\to F(\{a,b\})$ given by $f(x)=a^2,f(y)=ab,f(z)=b^2$. So by UMP of $F(\{x,y,z\})$ there is a unique $\phi: F(\{x,y,z\})\to F(\{a,b\})$ (homomorphism) such that $f=\phi \circ i$ i.e $\phi(x)=a^2,\, \phi(y)=ab,\, \phi(z)=b^2$. So $F(\{x,y,z\})/ker(\phi)$ is (isomorphic to) a subgroup of $F(\{a,b\})$ and hence free.

**So can we conclude from this that $ker(\phi)$ is trivial**?? We will be done if this happens.

A more general question (possibly wrong) can be formulated as follows :

**If $\psi : F(X)\to F(Y)$ is a surjective homomorphism between free groups, is $ker(\psi)$ trivial**??

(Edit): So may be a better way to formulate the general question would be : **If $F(X)$ is a free group and a factor group $F(X)/N$ is also free then does that imply the normal subgroup $N$ to be trivial**?? I am having a feeling that the answer to this question is in affirmative but I am nowhere near a solution.

P.S: There could be some possible directions to prove this using fundamental groups, but my algebraic topology is quite rusty (hence didn't tag it) so I would prefer algebraic attempts. But anyways, all ideas are welcome and thanks in advance. Also I am not really good at finding counterexamples in questions related to free group, so if this question is stupid, please ignore.

Comment: For your more general question: A surjective homomorphism between free groups has trivial kernel if and only if it is an isomorphism, by the definition of an isomorphism. However, if $|X|>|Y|$ then $F(X)\twoheadrightarrow F(Y)$ (either use the universal property of free groups, or realise the surjection explicitly by killing $|X|-|Y|$-many elements from $X$). Therefore, there exist surjections which are not injections.

Answer (score 2):

I'll make atry to prove that $ker(\phi)=1$. Let $T=\langle a^2,ab,b^2 \rangle$. It suffies to show that $a^2,ab,b^2$ freely generate $H$. Equivalently the elements $$x=a^2(ab)^{-1}=a^2b^{-1}a^{-1},\ y=ab,\ z=b^2(ab)^{-1}=ba^{-1}$$ freely generate $H$. In any non-cancelling product of two of $x^{\pm1},y^{\pm1},z^{\pm1}$ there is always some $a^{\pm1}$ or $b^{\pm1}$. Hence no such word reduces to the identity and it follows that $H$ is freely generated by $x,y,z$.

For your second question, if $\psi: F(X)\to F(Y)$ is surjective and $ker(\psi)$ is trivial then it is an isomorphism. But I can't find a surjective homomorphism $F(s,t,w)\to F(k,l)$ which is not injective (since a group on $3$ letters is not isomorphic to a group on $2$ letters).

Comment: I believe your argument that $x$, $y$ and $z$ freely generate a subgroup of $F$, but unfortunately this subgroup is not equal to the subgroup generated by $a^2,ab,b^2$ - in fact $\langle x,y,z \rangle$ has infinite index in $\langle a^2,ab,b^2 \rangle$, which has index 2 in $F$. In fact your own proof shows that these subgroups cannot be equal, because $a^2$ does not contain a $b$ or a $b^{-1}$.

Comment: @Derek Holt You're right once again. I'm trying to see how to fix it

Comment: @Derek Holt I have edited my answer. Could you share your opinion?

Comment: The problem is that you have not made any attempt to justify your claim that there is always some $a$ or some $b$ in a non-cancelling product. I think you are better off working with the given generators. In a product involving $a^2$, only the first $a$ can cancel (with $b^{-1}a^{-1}$) with $a^{-2}$ only the second $a^{-1}$ can cancel, and similarly for $b^2$, $b^{-2}$.